# "Skip" method in a Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

In the Query Builder (`\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`), it is possible to use both the [`skip($n)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) and [`take($n)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) methods.

In a Collection (`\Illuminate\Support\Collection`), it's possible to use the [`take($n)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-take) function, but there is no `skip($n)` function.

Why is that and is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `skip($n)` method is indeed not included in the `Collection` class, but there is a function that does the same: [`slice($n)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-slice).

**QueryBuilder (taken from the documentation):**

> ```
> $users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you may use the limit and offset methods:
>
> ```
> $users = DB::table('users')
>                 ->offset(10)
>                 ->limit(5)
>                 ->get();
> ```

**Collection:**

```
collect([1, 2, 3, 4])->slice(2)->all(); //[3, 4]
```

Many of the methods in the `QueryBuilder` class are not available in the `Collection` class, and vice-versa. But both of them have similar functions, like `QueryBuilder`'s [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) function, you'd use `Collection`'s [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter) function to achieve similar results.

Answer (score 0):

The forPage method returns a new collection containing the items that would be present on a given page number. The method accepts the page number as its first argument and the number of items to show per page as its second argument:

```php
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);

$chunk = $collection->forPage(2, 3);

$chunk->all();
```

Comment: Can you explain further how this connects to the original question?